# Running websockets in my device

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I am doing a sample react-native application in which I use web sockets.

So, I am running the server in localhost 3000 it works fine in simulator but when running on physical device it is not connecting.

Can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: Do you connect your app to your server by using `localhost:3000` or you use the ip of your server ? If you use the adress `localhost`  it is normal that you can not connect with your physical device, since your server and your app are not running on the same device.

Comment: Yes so How can I run in my device what I have to put instead of localhost:3000

Comment: You need to set the IP of your server (your computer this time).

Comment: okay I will give a try thanks.